# How to simulate and run some servers on Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, simulation, simulator

I need a simulator to run some servers on Hadoop:

1. Able to work with database.
2. I want to run a Java on it and see its results.
3. Run the Hadoop without MapReduce

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is no place to request tailor-made tutorials or recipes. But if you place a [mcve] of what you tried so far, the community can help you. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't run servers on Hadoop. It's the other way around.

If you want to create a Hadoop environment without installing Hadoop on your own, then you can download a virtual machine or start an account with any of the major cloud providers

Hadoop just starts YARN and HDFS. If you want to run code that isn't MapReduce, you'll need to find/install another tool such as Spark, Pig, Hive, Flink, etc, each of which can be used to query databases, but are not one themselves